# Unable to retrieve JSON response

Tags: android, json

I have a url which serves data to my android application, i learnt from a tutorial and wrote some code. It works perfectly for other url's but this one

```
http://acolyteserv.appspot.com/Products/getProductMatchedList/?format=json&p0=galaxy&p1=4&p2=all
```

the code is:

```
private void testere()
{
    InputStream is = null;
    String result;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://acolyteserv.appspot.com/Products/getProductMatchedList/?format=json&p0=galaxy&p1=4&p2=all");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();


        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();


            Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }


}
```

If i use this URL the toast, result gives me an empty string, but if I use the example URL like

```
http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, i'm new to JSON and the whole web service world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your request params to your HttpEntity. Or use HttpGet instead

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! Silly mistake, its working fine. Changed it. I actually used an example, that had those parameters which i removed since i knew it wont be of use to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `HttpPost`, but not submitting any entity with the request.

Try using `HttpGet` instead. Given the names of the things in your URL etc, I suspect a GET is what you actually want.